# Destroying json array in delphi

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, destroy

The code below creates a memory leak.
What is the correct method?

```
  JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    JSONArray :=
      TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
        TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
          '[{"username":"admin"},{"username":"developer"}]'
        ), 0
      ) as TJSONArray;
  finally
    JSONArray.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the call to `TJSONArray.Create`.  You are creating your own `TJSONArray` object, then overwriting the `JSONArray` pointer to point at a completely different `TJSONArray` object, leaking the original object you `Create`'d.

So, simply get rid of that `Create` call, you don't need it.  You need to `Free` only the object that `ParseJSONValue()` returns.

Also, you don't need to convert the JSON string to bytes.  `ParseJSONValue()` has an overload that accepts a `string` as input.

Try this:

```pascal
JSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
  '[{"username":"admin"},{"username":"developer"}]'
) as TJSONArray;
try
  // ...
finally
  JSONArray.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as an alternative to the valid provided solution, but using [mORMot](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#SOURCE). IMHO simpler, cleaner and avoiding memory leaks:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Syncommons;

var Json : TDocVariantData;
begin
  Json.InitJSon('[{"username":"admin"},{"username":"developer"}]');
  // Testing
  assert(Json.Kind = dvArray);
  assert(Json.Count = 2);
  assert(TDocVariantData(Json.Values[1]).U['username'] = 'developer');
end.
```

Please, find further details and alternatives [in the amazing documentation](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_38).